# AngularJS service to send Twilio SMS messages

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've been experimenting with creating an AngularJS service that can be called from the controller and send text messages based on particular events in the application. The implementation is based on [this](http://jsfiddle.net/dekkard/w5ordwwd/), and works as follows:

Firstly, we have the service:

```
function BusinessService($http) {

  this.twilioSMS = {

    sendMessage: function(to, from, body) {

      var accountSid = 'xxx';
      var authToken = 'xxx';

      var testEndpoint = 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/' + accountSid + '/SMS/Messages.json';
      var liveEndpoint = 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/' + accountSid + '/Messages.json';

      var data = {
        To: to,
        From: from,
        Body: body
      };

      $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: testEndpoint,
        data: data,
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
          xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization",
            "Basic " + btoa(accountSid + ":" + authToken) // !
          );
        },
        success: function(data) {
          console.log("Got response: %o", data);
          if (typeof successCallback == 'function')
            successCallback(data);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          console.log("Request failed: " + textStatus + ", " + errorThrown);
          if (typeof failCallback == 'function')
            failCallback(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
        }
      })

    }

  }

}
```

Then setting it up in the controller:

```
function ConsumerBusinessProfileCtrl($scope, BusinessService) {

  $scope.sendMessage = function(to, from, body) {
    return BusinessService.twilioSMS.sendMessage(to, from, body)
  }

}
```

And then calling it from the view:

```
<a ng-click="sendMessage('+12345678901', '+15005550006', 'Hey Jenny! Good luck on the bar exam!')">Send Message</a>
```

I've tested the [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/dekkard/w5ordwwd/) with my accountSid, authToken, and phone numbers and it is working fine. But my implementation fails with a `401 (UNAUTHORIZED)` error. A part of me thinks that this is because `$http` does not support `beforeSend` or `afterSend`. But I am not sure? Can anybody here guide me in the right direction?

Comment: How did you implement authentication.

Comment: @RomanC authentication takes place at `beforeSend` with the `accountSid` and `authToken` variables, I've done some googling and found that it is in fact a jQuery doesn't actually support this, but recommends the use of interceptors. Sadly, I am not too familiar with this concept, and how to implement it in my case.

Comment: The interceptors are too furious concept without code it's off-topic.

Comment: @RomanC fair enough, that's understandable I guess. Is there anything else I can do in my case to implement authentication?

Comment: Write a code and post it to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changed $http to the following to fix things:

```
 $http({
  method: 'POST',
  url: testEndpoint,
  data: data,
  transformRequest: function(obj) {
    var str = [];
    for (var p in obj)
      str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
    return str.join("&");
  },
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa(accountSid + ':' + authToken),
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  },
}).success(function(response) {
  console.log(response);
}).error(function(error) {
  console.log(error);
});
}
```

Comment: I ran into the same problem for first time twilio integration.  The `transformRequest` got it working for me.  Thanks.